AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'model_body'
I had meet some erros, at begin I think maybe I download the model wrongly， then I redo download but the errors still exist，my python version == 3.11.7 and sentence-transformers ==2.31.0， my transformers version == 4.44.2 , jesus crisp, you guys know how to fix it?
redo download the model but it doesn't work
raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).name}' object has no attribute '{name}'") AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'model_body' #2942

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
